# How do I retrieve content submitted by a form on the server?

Tags: node.js

I try to get the content submitted by the form node.js（express）.The method is `POST`.But the content the content I got is clear rather than secret.Like `this:username=hushiyun&password=19941022918`.

Here is my part of code:

```js
app.post('/postmsg',(req,res)=>{
    let allData = '';
    req.on("data",(data)=>{
        allData += data;
    });
    req.once("end",()=>{
        console.log(allData);
    });
    res.send('hello world')
});
```

```html
<form action="http://127.0.0.1/postmsg" method="post">
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please show the `<form>`.  What is the encoding of the request?

Comment: What do you mean by *clear rather than secret*?

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand your question, but you can access the form data sent by the client into `req.body` by using `body-parser`. Check the Express documentation for that: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body and https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware for handling form-data, then you can access the parsed body using `req.body`.

```
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');

var opts = {
    // https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(opts));

app.post('/postmsg', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```